# How to install koha in my windows 8.1 with xampp....?

Tags: windows, perl, installation

I have windows, xampp and oracle_VM_Virtual Box. How can I install koha and where do I find this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're probably aware, since you have VirtualBox installed, you can't run Koha on Windows -- it needs a Linux platform

You should create an Ubuntu virtual machine on VirtualBox, and then I suggest you take a look at the installation instructions [*Koha on Ubuntu*](https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Koha_on_ubuntu_-_packages)

Essentially it boils down to these command-line operations

```
echo deb http://debian.koha-community.org/koha stable main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/koha.list

wget -O- http://debian.koha-community.org/koha/gpg.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get install koha-common
```

Comment: Thanks i complete create an Ubuntu virtual machine on VirtualBox
then info you please next step setup info me..!
thanks regard.

Comment: @illeas: It is all explained in the link I gave you

Comment: @illeas: I've added to my answer